# Copying a worksheet from one workbook to another into an existing worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Sub CopySheet()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("TestData.xlsm")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("AutoBE.xlsm")
    
    wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
       
End Sub
```

This manages to copy Sheet1 from TestData into the AutoBE workbook. However, it creates a new sheet due to the `Copy After`

Is there a way to insert the data into an existing worksheet in AutoBE such as Sheet1 itself, assuming for simplicity that it is empty? I have looked everywhere online and forums and no luck. Is this even possible? With experience with python I fell as though it must be.

Alternatively is there a way to create this new sheet in AutoBE as this code does but then deleting all other sheets in AutoBE apart from the newly created one?

Comment: There are several ways to tackle this. You could copy the used range to overwrite the destination worksheet. You could copy like in your code and delete `Sheet1` and then rename the copy to `Sheet1`. Is that an option? Are there any references to the destination worksheet from other worksheets (then it isn't an option)? Could you share a screenshot of the worksheet? What does *"but then deleting all other sheets in AutoBE apart from the newly created one"* mean? Why would you do this? Please clarify and share any additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 'Replace' Worksheet

- Here is a simple example of how you could proceed.
- If this doesn't work for you, share what's wrong with it so we can improve.

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Sub CopyWorksheet()
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks("TestData.xlsm")
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks("AutoBE.xlsm")
    ' Reference the old worksheet...
    Dim dwsOld As Worksheet: Set dwsOld = dwb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' and store its name and its code name in variables.
    Dim dName As String: dName = dwsOld.Name
    Dim dCodeName As String: dCodeName = dwsOld.CodeName
    
    ' Copy.
    
    sws.Copy After:=dwsOld
    
    ' Reference the new (copied) worksheet.
    Dim dwsNew As Worksheet: Set dwsNew = dwsOld.Next
    
    ' Delete the old worksheet.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
        dwsOld.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    ' Rename the new worksheet and restore the old code name.
    dwsNew.Name = dName
    dwb.VBProject.VBComponents(dwsNew.CodeName).Name = dCodeName
       
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and thanks for the clear comments etc

Comment: I don't want to edit this question but I was hoping you might eb able to help with one that builds on this one. Ie how to copy a specific range from one sheet to another sheet in a different workbook. Would eb greatly appreciated

Comment: Best ask another question presenting a practical example e.g. how to copy `wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:JLastRow")` to  `wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")`. Also, add which workbook contains the code, which workbooks are open, if there is any data in the destination workbook,... etc. And of course, add a code.

Comment: I have asked it as a new question and made these changes, please let me know if there's anything else I should clarify https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74328220/how-to-copy-a-specific-range-from-one-worksheet-to-another-worksheet-in-another