# How to copy a specific range from one worksheet to another worksheet in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks:
Source.xlsm, sheet= Orig and
Destination.xlsm, sheet=New

I am trying to move data between these sheets in a specific way: Example of both sheets before running the macro (the column ordering is on purpose)

[image]
[image]

In the Orig sheet, cell F1 is storing today's date in the following format: dd mmm yy

My objective is to take only the rows from Orig with today's date and place all of them in a specific ordering to the end of the New sheet. So that after running the macro, New looks like:

[image]

Any suggestions as to how to progress would be amazing

I have the following code snippets to start to form a solution, all saved in Source.xlsm. This correctly select the bottom two rows of Orig since they have todays date in column D

```
Sub SelectTodayRows()
    Dim tableR As Range, cell As Range, r As Range
    Dim s As String
    Set tableR = Range("D1:D100000")
    Set r = Range("F1") 
    For Each cell In tableR
      If cell = r Then
      s = s & cell.Row & ":" & cell.Row & ", "
      End If
    Next cell
    s = Left(s, Len(s) - 2)
    Range(s).Select
   
End Sub
```

The next step is appending these selected rows in the correct column ordering to New.

Comment: The idea is not that bad but unfortunately, the Range.Address property only recognizes up to 255 or so characters so you need to abandon this idea. Does any of these workbooks contain this code? Do you want to append the new data or delete the previous, and then write the new data? Where is your data located, e.g. `A2:ZLastRow`? Could you add a screenshot of your data (source worksheet)?

Comment: Sure, I'll create a simpler example and update the question with pictures

Comment: @VBasic2008 I've updated it, please let me know if this is doable and if any additional explanations would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Data to Different Columns

```vb
Sub TransferToday()
    
    Const CriteriaColumn As Variant = 4
    ' The leading "0, "-s are used to be able to use sCols(c)
    ' instead of sCols(c - 1) in the For...Next loop.
    Dim sCols() As Variant: sCols = VBA.Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
    Dim dCols() As Variant: dCols = VBA.Array(0, 2, 4, 3, 1)
    
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(sCols)
    Dim Today As Date: Today = Date ' TODAY() in excel
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks("Destination.xlsm")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets("New")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, cCount)
    
    ' Prevent copying if an occurrence of today's date is found in destination.
    ' If not needed, out-comment or delete, it doesn't interfere with the rest.
    Dim dCol As Variant
    dCol = dCols(Application.Match(CriteriaColumn, sCols, 0) - 1)
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(CLng(Today), drg.Columns(dCol), 0)) Then
        MsgBox "Today's data had already been transferred.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Orig")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, cCount)
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To srCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        If IsDate(sData(sr, CriteriaColumn)) Then ' is a date
            If sData(sr, CriteriaColumn) = Today Then ' is today's date
                dr = dr + 1
                For c = 1 To cCount
                    dData(dr, dCols(c)) = sData(sr, sCols(c))
                Next c
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
    
    If dr = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No today's data found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' First Destination Row.
    Dim dfrrg As Range: Set dfrrg = drg.Resize(1).Offset(drg.Rows.Count)
    
    dfrrg.Resize(dr).Value = dData
   
    MsgBox "Today's data transferred.", vbInformation
   
End Sub
```

The following might be useful if the dates are strings.

```vb
Const DateFormat As String = "dd mmm yy"
Dim TodayString As String
' Either...
TodayString = Format(Date, DateFormat)
' ... or...
TodayString = Application.Text(Date, DateFormat) ' not English locale
' ... and there is only one If statement:
If CStr(sData(sr, CriteriaColumn)) = TodayString Then
```

The *prevent copying...* block might also need modifying.

Comment: I understand sCols, meaning Name=1, product=2, quantity=3 and date=4. So dicols should be 0,4,1,3,2. Your version of dcols works but unsure as to why.

Comment: Also, is there a way to have a column space between the copied data ie the data would be copied in to New with the following columns: Date | Name | Quantity | Age| Product. So all columns apart from Age would be filled in as seen already? Thanks again

Comment: Its still not obvious to me why 1234, becomes 2431, since there is no logic for these changes in numbers given the changes in column orderings. Apologies if I'm missing something but 1234 becoming 2431 makes no sense to me

Comment: A quick fix would be to modify the following: `dCols = VBA.Array(0, 2, 5, 3, 1)`, `Set drg = dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion`, `ReDim dData(1 To srCount, 1 To drg.Columns.Count)`. But this is messing up things. You should have mentioned that initially.

Comment: I apologise, I forgot to mention this aspect of the task. I'll ask it as another questions and thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, I think this should finally clear it up. I am thinking that source columns `1,2,3,4` will become destination columns `2,4,3,1`. You are thinking that source columns `4,1,3,2` will become destination columns `1,2,3,4`. It works either way. To make it work in your way, use `sCols = VBA.Array(0, 4, 1, 3, 2)` and `dCols = VBA.Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the explanation. I've posted a slight extension of this question, would be awesome to get your help